# rootfs does not contain systemd's service

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto

Hello I've got a recipe with the following structure:

```
- my-recipe:
  - files:
    - hhctrl-mgmt.service
  - my_recipe.bb
```

My recipe's code is as follows:

```
SUMMARY = "Henhouse Management Application"
SECTION = ""
LICENSE = "MIT"

inherit pkgconfig cmake systemd

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/pblxptr/hhctrl-mgmt.git;protocol=https;tag=master"
SRC_URI_append = " file://hhctrl-mgmt.service"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=6f6c3b7faa0513f8653c977c58af38f5"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

DEPENDS += "boost curl spdlog fmt"
EXTRA_OECMAKE = ""


SYSTEMD_AUTO_ENABLE = "enable"

do_install () {
  install -m 0755 -d ${D}${bindir}
  install -d ${D}/${systemd_system_unitdir}
  install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/hhctrl-mgmt.service ${D}/${systemd_system_unitdir}

SYSTEMD_SERVICE = "hhctrl-mgmt.service"
```

As you can see, the recipe uses cmake project downloaded from github. Then it configures and builds it. Also under the files directory, there is a file describing systemd's service.

Everything works ok (my app is being built and copied to /usr/bin), until bitbake tries to configure service. When I use the recipe's code as above, I'm not able to find my service in rootfs. On the other hand when I move SYSTEMD_SERVICE = "hhctrl-mgmt.service" over the do_install then I'm getting an error saying that it:

> Didn't find service unit specified in SYSTEMD_SERVICE

Do you know what could be wrong in my .bb file?

Comment: _I'm not able to find my service in rootfs_ -- this is a bit vague but if you mean the service binary, you don't install anything into bindir in your example

Comment: Does your DISTRO_FEATURES contain `systemd`? If not, the `rm_systemd_unitdir` function in `systemd.bbclass` will be removing the service files. Also, you should use `SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN}` to specify which package the service file apples to.